# Magnolia headless login

Tags: java, headless, magnolia

What steps do I need to take to implement user login?

I am using PUR & REST modules. I was able to successfully login using REST endpoint using MgnlContext.login, but if I try to access another endpoint I get 401.

What I have so far:

```
CredentialsCallbackHandler handler = new PlainTextCallbackHandler(username, password.toCharArray(), "public");
SecuritySupport securitySupport = Components.getComponent( SecuritySupport.class );
LoginResult result = securitySupport.authenticate(handler, SecuritySupportBase.DEFAULT_JAAS_LOGIN_CHAIN);
MgnlContext.login(result.getSubject());
```

I think I need to get session cookie (that's configured in web.xml) to send with any subsequent request, but where do I get it in the endpoint? And do I need to preserve it myself? Or is it something else entirely?

Both Magnolia and frontend run on localhost, but on different ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnolia was sending the cookie all the time (as Set-Cookie header), it just never got saved. I had to process it manually for my FE to set the cookie and send it back in every subsequent request.